# How Do I Play An Animation In Unity 5.3.4?

Tags: unity, animation

I am confused on how to play an animation with the new unity version because the flag "Automatically Play Animation" is gone.  I cant have the animation connected to my GameObject because it plays right away.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FPSCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float lookSensitivity = 5;
    private float xRotation;
    private float yRotation;
    private float currentRotationX;
    private AnimationClip walking;

    void Start() {
        // DONT KNOW HOW TO FIND AND START WALKING ANIMATION CLIP
    }
    void Update() {
        yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
        xRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
    }
}
```

[image: pic or game]

Comment: Are you using Animation or Animator component?

Comment: It is an animator with a animation and a controller

Comment: Is your animation orange color?

Comment: no it is not, even if i set it to public i cant drag it

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Animator screen and the animated object Inspector info

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up states in the animator panel. You can open it by double clicking on a animation controller. To create a animation controller just drag the animation Clip onto the gameObject you want. Once you have the animator panel opened you need to create a parameter to handle the transitions. Here is a picture of a example Animator set up. [image]
Then you use a script that looks something like this to set the transition.

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator animator;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        animator.SetBool("startWalking", true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

}
```

Comment: it wont let me drag it there

Comment: if you have a animator you need to change the variable type to Animator, then check the scripting API on how to use the Animator.

Comment: i changed it to an animation clip

Comment: i still cant play the animation clip once I add the Object to the public Animation.

Comment: give me a screenshot of what you have and I will answer you correcty.

Comment: i added the picture of what i have